# Java: "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XYZ" exception, even though already defined in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am getting a no persistence provider exception, but I already defined the provider in persistence.xml. This is a Maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="XYZ" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>model.XYZ</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have EclipseLink available in your classpath?

Comment: @JuanMoreno I am new to Java...this is a section of my classpath. Does this answer your question?
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">

Comment: Well, my question is related to how you manage your dependencies? Is it a maven project? Is your app package as a war?

Comment: @JuanMoreno It is a Maven project.

Comment: How do you try to obtain the `EntityMagager`? If you use newer versiond of jpa, try to use `jakarta` instead of `javax`.

Comment: Could you share with us your pom.xml dependencies section? You need to have in there the EclipseLink dependency. Also, do you deploy on an application server? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 2):

If the application use the new jakarta namespace, you need to add the [3.0.0](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/3.0.php) or newer version to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Else, we need to use the previous one, eg [2.7.8](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.7.php):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```